# hideEffect not triggered when component visible property set false programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, effects

In Flex I've got a component, which is based on a Canvas.
It looks like this (I removed the `<mx:Script>` for better reading):

```
<mx:Canvas verticalScrollPolicy="off" showEffect="showFX" hideEffect="hideFX" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" creationComplete="doComplete()" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="63" height="63">

<mx:Fade id="hideFX" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" easingFunction="mx.effects.easing.Linear.easeIn" startDelay="0" duration="600" />
<mx:Fade id="showFX" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" easingFunction="mx.effects.easing.Linear.easeIn" startDelay="0" duration="600" />

</mx:Canvas>
```

If I set `customComponent.Visible` to `false`, the component gets hidden (as expected). But doesn't trigger the `hideFX` at all. Am I doing something wrong? Or isn't this the correct way to use hideEffect and showEffect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, try binding the effects to the `Canvas`:

```
<mx:Canvas verticalScrollPolicy="off" showEffect="{showFX}" hideEffect="{hideFX}" ... >
```